# Bind another CELL value into the Showlink option in Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, jqgrid

I have two values in my table where i store FormName and FormPath.

Ex: FormName will contains the "Click For New Version"
    FormPath will contains the "../Attachments/pdf/Forms/pressForm.pdf"

So In my Jqgrid i have to show one column that will show the text as FormName and the HREF URL as FormPath.

So how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

i have found a way to do this like.

```js
  {
                             name: 'FormPath',
                             index: 'FormPath',
                             editable: true,
                             formatter: GetFormURL
                             }
```

```js
 function GetFormURL(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                  debugger;
                  return '<a href="' + cellvalue + '">' + rowObject.Category + '</a>';
                  //return '<img src="' + cellvalue + '" />';
              }
```